# Cannot load resource from pod library

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, swift4

After installing the library https://github.com/AAChartModel/AAChartKit-Swift via cocoapods, I tried to run the samples given in the repository.

I'm getting the following error

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

.. on these lines (in the library, I didn't wrote them)

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "AAChartView", ofType: "html", inDirectory: "AAJSFiles.bundle")
let urlStr = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: path!)
```

I can't figure out how to fix it... It seems that the resources folder doesn't get copied into the bundle when building.

This is the piece of code I'm executing:

```
    let chart = AAChartView()
    chart.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
    self.view.addSubview(chart)

    let model = AAChartModel.init()
        .chartType(AAChartType.Column)//Can be any of the chart types listed under `AAChartType`.
        .animationType(AAChartAnimationType.Bounce)
        .title("TITLE")//The chart title
        .subtitle("subtitle")//The chart subtitle
        .dataLabelEnabled(false) //Enable or disable the data labels. Defaults to false
        .tooltipValueSuffix("USD")//the value suffix of the chart tooltip
        .categories(["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
                     "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"])
        .colorsTheme(["#fe117c","#ffc069","#06caf4","#7dffc0"])
        .series([
            AASeriesElement()
                .name("Tokyo")
                .data([7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6])
                .toDic()!,
            AASeriesElement()
                .name("New York")
                .data([0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5])
                .toDic()!,
            AASeriesElement()
                .name("Berlin")
                .data([0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0])
                .toDic()!,
            AASeriesElement()
                .name("London")
                .data([3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8])
                .toDic()!,])
    chart.aa_drawChartWithChartModel(model)
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by:

1. Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources menu, click on +
2. Click on 'Add Other...'
3. Navigate into your Pods folder, and select the bundle file, in my case it was AAJSFile.bundle

This will add a reference from your project to the bundle so it will properly find it within your namespace next time.

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "AAChartView", ofType: "html", inDirectory: "AAJSFiles.bundle"
```

expexts to load from main bundle not the pod bundle you need

```
let podBundle = Bundle(identifier:"hereSet")!
let path = podBundle.path(forResource: "AAChartView", ofType: "html", inDirectory: "AAJSFiles.bundle")
```

//

[image]

Comment: How can I know the value for identifier?

Is there any other way to fix this without changing the library code? That library seems quite famous to have such a simple error...

Comment: see edit ......... the crash is because the main bundle has no relation to what you're looking for